# iOS iframe too wide

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've checked a lot of different solutions to this problem, javascript handling, different css tricks with a container div, and more but I cannot get my iframe to work on iOS. the code I have is -

```
<div class = "container" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
<iframe src="web.html" runat="server" allowfullscreen="yes" marginwidth="0" style="margin: auto;" name="iframe_a" width="100%" class = "home-page-iframe" id = "iframeMain" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

you can see the code live at https://rhovell.github.io/portfolio/index.html

currently there is no javascript.

```
/* iframe styling */
.home-page-iframe {
max-width: 100vw;
min-height: 300px;
border: none;
margin: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
}
.container {
width: 1px;
min-width: 100%;
*width: 100%;
max-width: 100vw;
overflow:auto;
}
```

I want the iframe restricted to the device width. There is a separate css file handling media query changes to objects within the iframe pages (and on the index). there is also interactive content in all iframe pages.